# How to know if view's frame.maxY was already scrolled on top of screen?

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview

I have a label inside the view, and the view was inside of a UIScrollView `(UIScrollView -> UIView -> UILabel)`

I can see the bottom of my UILabel using `label.frame.maxY`, I want to run a function if that bottom of the label was already scrolled up on the top of the screen (already not visible).

How can I know if I already scrolled it enough on top of the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `contentOffset` of the scroll view. Base on this value you will know whether your button is visible or not at a given time.

```
func isButtonVisible() -> Bool {
  return contentOffset.y < buttonSuperView.frame.y + button.frame.maxY
}
```